# Hi I am trying to develop insert functionality using python and postgress

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Hi I am trying to develop insert functionality using python and postgress sql. What I am trying to achieve is that when Insert a value, the id should be auto incremented as I have set it that way. But still gives me an error of non null. See error below

This is my current code:

```
def insert(car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber):
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='Car_Inventory_db' user='postgres' password='password' host='localhost' port='5432'")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT into carInventory(car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (car_make,car_model,year,first_owner,vinnumber))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Error I am receiving:

```
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" of relation "carinventory" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Honda, Civic, 2003, true, 3sdfSKHAN).
```

This is how I created my table

```
def connect():
   conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='Car_Inventory_db' user='postgres' password='password' host='localhost' port='5432'")
   cur=conn.cursor()
   cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carInventory(
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    car_make text,
    car_model text,
    year integer,
    first_owner boolean,
    vinnumber varchar(17)
)
""")
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
```

How do I avoid the error, so my code takes in all the value, and only auto increment the id column based on the insert statement

Answer (score 2):

Use SERAIL data type in your table definition.

This will do the auto-increment for you.

```
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

See [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

As of Postgres v10 the preferred method is to define your `id` as a [generated identity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtable.html) column.

```
create table carinventory(                                                                                                                         
             id integer  generated always as identity                                                                                              
                         primary key                                                                                                               
           , car_make text                                                                                                                         
           , car_model text                                                                                                                        
           , year integer                                                                                                                          
           , first_owner boolean                                                                                                                   
           , vinnumber varchar(17)                                                                                                                 
           ) ;
```